# Individual column searching on specific columns, DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've seen examples of how to apply individual column searches for each column of a DataTable either using text box, or drop down menus containing the returned values per column. However, I've not yet come across any mechanism to only apply them to specific columns. For example, using the below would apply the search text box to all except coloumn zero:

```
$('#DataTable tfoot th:gt(0)').each(function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" 
    style="width:120px;"  placeholder="search ' + title + '" />');
});
```

But, how would I then also remove it from column 6 & 7 for example?

*** UPDATE *** This question relates to server side processing only. Should of stated that earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personnaly use column definition in combination with iniComplete callBack.
In this example two types of search, you can add as many different searches (even no search)

```
$('#table').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/flux/ajax",
                "dataSrc": "data",
                "scrollX": true
            },
            "columns": [                    
                {className: "select", "title": "Status", "data": "stat"}
                {className: "text", "title": "Libellé", "data": "Lib"}}
            ],
            initComplete: function () {

                this.api().columns().every(function () {
                    var column = this;
                    if ($(column.header()).hasClass('select')) {
                        console.log(column);
                        var select = $('<select><option value="">' + $(column.header()).html() + '</option></select>')
                                .appendTo($(column.header()).empty())
                                .on('change', function (e) {
                                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                            $(this).val()
                                            );
                                    column
                                            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                                            .draw();
                                    return false;
                                });
                        column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                            select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
                        });
                    } else if ($(column.header()).hasClass('text')) {
                        var text = $('<input type="text" placeholder="' + $(column.header()).html() + '" />')
                                .appendTo($(column.header()).empty())
                                .on('keyup change', function () {
                                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                        $(this).val()
                                        );
                                    if (column.search() !== this.value) {
                                        column
                                                .search(val)
                                                .draw();
                                    }
                                    return false;
                                });

                    }

                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi Sylvain, perhaps I should of added that this is all server side processing. Nice work though, I can see how this can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this (by title)

```
    $('#DataTable tfoot th:gt(0)').each(function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        if (title != "columns 6 title" && title != "columns 7 title")
        {
            $(this).html('<input type="text" 
            style = "width:120px;"  placeholder = "search ' + title + '" /> ');
        }
    });
```